# Custom JSON output in Apache Camel xmljson

Tags: json, xml, xml-parsing, apache-camel

Camel Route :

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

   <dataFormats>
    <xmljson id="xmljson" />
   </dataFormats>

    <route id="route1">
        <from uri="file:C:/Users/User1/InputXML"/>
        <to uri="activemq:queue:MyThread1"/>        
    </route>

    <route id="route2">
        <from uri="activemq:queue:MyThread1"/>    
        <marshal ref="xmljson"/> 
        <bean ref="com.test.OutputProcessor"/>
    </route> 
</camelContext>
```

Input XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Message>
  <to> Tove</to>
 <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</Message>
```

Actual output :

```
{"to":" Tove","from":"Jani","heading":"Reminder","body":"Don't forget me this weekend!"}
```

I want to customize this output. i want to add some mote attributes to the converted json. For Example i want the output json as

```
  {
    "inputs":[  
                { 
            "inputname":"to",
            "inputValue":"Tove"
            },
            { 
            "inputname":"from",
            "inputValue":"jani"
            },
            { 
            "inputname":"heading",
            "inputValue":"Reminder"
            },
            { 
            "inputname":"body",
            "inputValue":"Don't forget me this weekend!"
            }
        ]
    }
```

How this can be achieved ?

Comment: Look at content en-richer and message translator EIP in Apache Camel.

Comment: Are you essentially asking how to convert multiple strings into a single chunk of JSON (held in a variable) in the format you showed, each consisting of a group 4 pairs of data? 
Or could there be more more than 4 pairs of data, eg `CC` value?

Comment: There could be more pairs. What i actually want is to add custom attributes , like "inputname" or"inputtype" in JSon , which are not a part of XML.

Answer (score 1):

I think an `AggregationStrategy` might help:

1) Fist you add the aggregationStrategy to your route:

```
<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <route>
    <from uri="direct:start"/>
    <enrich strategyRef="aggregationStrategy">
      <constant>direct:resource</constant>
    <to uri="direct:result"/>
  </route>
  <route>
    <from uri="direct:resource"/>
    ...
  </route>
</camelContext>

<bean id="aggregationStrategy" class="com.ExampleAggregationStrategy" />
```

2) Then create the class that will get the **Body of the message** and transform it the way you want, and set the body to the Exchange again. 
*OBS: Here You will need to use a **`xml` API** to add the attributes you want to add.*

```
public class ExampleAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {

    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange original, Exchange resource) {
        Object originalBody = original.getIn().getBody();
        Object resourceResponse = resource.getIn().getBody();
        Object mergeResult = ... // combine original body and resource response
        if (original.getPattern().isOutCapable()) {
            original.getOut().setBody(mergeResult);
        } else {
            original.getIn().setBody(mergeResult);
        }
        return original;
    }

}
```

More [here](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html).

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything preventing you from using an XSLT component? You can apply that to bring the input XML to a format that directly maps to your desired output JSON format and then push it to xmljson e.g. - (need some clean up to avoid some blank elements)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="Message">
        <inputs>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <inputname><xsl:value-of select="name()" /> </inputname>
        <inputvalue><xsl:value-of select="." /></inputvalue>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </inputs>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Nothing preventing.. XSLT is working like gem. i have been using xsl from last few months . Now i want to use this camel feature .

Comment: To best of my knowledge, xmljson component will not give you much control to transform / change the kind of JSON objects are generated. You need to feed it XML that is close to JSON you want - for that you should use XSLT component of Camel.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Jackson library.  You can programmatically change the output format.  Unmarshal is only good for direct mapping and not enrichment.  Essentially Unmarshal to xml,  add a processor and then create your output Json format.